# Inconsistancy betwwen run-app and war execution

Tags: grails

I have a Grails application which does not need database (it is a REST client). When I run it with `grails run-app` everything is as planned. But when I run it in Tomcat as war I get the following message:

```
Class:    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Message:  1
Trace:     Line | Method
->> 1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    617 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: 1
->>   38 | runWorker in /index.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
->>   64 | doCall    in gsp_coreQueriesindex_gsp$_run_closure2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     88 | run       in gsp_coreQueriesindex_gsp
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

I do not know where to focus. I used Maven and Ivy without any result.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going wrong. When you do a run-app the it uses the dev environment and when you do a grails war then it uses the prod environment to generate a war. You could try looking into the environment settings to see if something is wrong.

Comment: There are differences between prod and dev modes. For example on dev mode flash messages do not work, and that is not documented anywhere.

Comment: the one thing in the past, that helped me find problems like this, was doing a `grails run-war` which more often than not revealed the same problems (given your tomcat and java versions are rather close).  this way you can debug in your local environment.

Comment: @lxknvlk never had such issue (on other hand I didn't use flash.message with latest versions). it's clearly a bug, so if you faced it it's good idea to raise issue in Grails Jira

Comment: Sorry. One dude tested on prod env, he had no problems with flash messages. Looks like problem is in my setup.

Comment: Many thanks for your support.I replaced the index.gsp with a simpler page and everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your support. I replaced the index.gsp page with a simpler one and everything is OK.